# openvpn rdp networking mystery : can connect HTTP cannot RDP, even with firewall off

Tags: windows, networking, openvpn, rdp

I have 2 small networks joined using OpenVpn (routed configuration), lets call them A and B.

on A, I have a test web server (IIS, Windows 2008R2 or Windows 2012 depending on test machine), lets call it webA :

1. I can connect to it from network A (both RDP and HTTP)
2. I cannot connect via RDP to webA from network B
3. I can ping webA from network B
4. I cannot connect to webA using : telnet webA 3389
   Here things starts getting real strange :
5. I can connect to webA using HTTP
6. AFTER I connect to webA using HTTP, I can connect to webA using RDP ???
7. Similar behavior can be observed in the reverse situation ( i.e. connecting to webB from network A). This is not entirely consistent since just about any direct connection, once established, can restore connectivity for other services).
8. Some machines, but not all, of network A cannot reach web servers of network B. This seems to be firewall related (disabling the firewall seems to make it work, even if listing the rules via *netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name=all* does not seem to show any significant differences).
9. this happens on other VMs too, and other protocols can sometime activate the connection : for instance connecting to an Oracle test database will unblock RDP.

This happens with or without the firewall on webA (windows firewall).

Any pointer or suggestion would be appreciated (as well as pointer to any tool that could be used to diagnose the problem).

**Edit 1:** : Answering the question about arp tables : (they don't change before / after )

PS C:\Users\Administrator> arp -a

Interface: 192.168.69.45 --- 0x11
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  192.168.69.1          00-26-91-9c-19-57     dynamic
  192.168.69.20         00-26-b9-82-ea-8d     dynamic
  192.168.69.23         00-24-e8-e1-31-00     dynamic
  192.168.69.24         68-5d-43-0c-96-c1     dynamic
  192.168.69.30         00-26-b9-82-ea-8f     dynamic
  192.168.69.34         00-90-f5-d6-d8-a7     dynamic
  192.168.69.255        ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
  224.0.0.2             01-00-5e-00-00-02     static
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
  224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     static
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
  224.0.0.253           01-00-5e-00-00-fd     static
  224.0.1.24            01-00-5e-00-01-18     static
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static

Interface: 10.69.12.1 --- 0x12
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  10.69.12.2            00-ff-40-87-32-62     dynamic
  10.69.12.3            ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
  224.0.0.2             01-00-5e-00-00-02     static
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
  224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     static
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
  224.0.0.253           01-00-5e-00-00-fd     static
  224.0.1.24            01-00-5e-00-01-18     static
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static

Interface: 10.69.75.6 --- 0x13
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  10.69.75.5            00-ff-02-4f-94-61     dynamic
  10.69.75.7            ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
  224.0.0.2             01-00-5e-00-00-02     static
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
  224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     static
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
  224.0.0.253           01-00-5e-00-00-fd     static
  224.0.1.24            01-00-5e-00-01-18     static
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
PS C:\Users\Administrator>

**Edit 2:**

as i rebooted this morning, I rechecked :

1. ping srv-sinv3 ==> OK  <== well tcp/ip works
2. telnet srv-sinv3 3389 ==> **KO**
3. telnet srv-sinv3 80 ==> OK <== well tcp/ip works
4. telnet srv-sinv3 3389 ==> OK <=== **??? WHY** connecting to port 80 (IIS) sudendly unlocks 3389 ?

Comment: As a possible troublesthooting step, could you get your ARP table while the connection isn't working, then again when it is working?

Comment: I edited the original post to add this information.

Comment: What does `netstat -a -b` show? Is the svchost.exe listening? does prcomon.exe (option: `show network activity`) show any activity?